# How do I plot from data frames?

Tags: r, dataframe, plot

From the following code, I got a data frame in R. I am trying to plot the data frame; however, I am only interested in the score they got on the Final. So I want the x-axis to be the number of students, which is 6, since that's how many data points their are, and I want the y-axis to be Final. Is there a way to do this from just the data frame?

```
data <- data.frame(Score1=c(100,36,58,77,99,92),Score2=c(56,68,68,98,15,35), Final=c(63,87,89,45,99,18))
```

Output listed below:

```
  Score1 Score2 Final
1    100     56    63
2     36     68    87
3     58     68    89
4     77     98    45
5     99     15    99
6     92     35    18
```

Or will I have to do something like this instead? But this gives me an error that the lengths are not the same.

```
data <- data.frame(Score1=c(100,36,58,77,99,92),Score2=c(56,68,68,98,15,35))
Final=c(63,87,89,45,99,18)
f.data <- cbind(data,Final)
b <- 6
plot(b,Final)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following

```
library(ggplot2);

qplot( x = 1:6, y = data$Final)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below can do the trick.

`plot(data$Final)`